# Why downvotes to question?

Tags: support, down-votes

I have been hanging around physics SE for quite a while. I am just a student who craves for some knowledge in mathematics and physics and thus I joined SE. I am not an expert.

But to my questions, I receive downvotes and the reason is not specified. The problem is not the downvotes to my question. Anyone can downvote my question, but a reason can be specified to give a real meaning to that downvote. Only when the mistake is shown can we move forward to correct it. At least a suggestion to improve the question can be given in comments.

Not only to my question. Most of the questions that are simple are getting downvoted, even when enough necessary information is provided to give an excellent answer. But not everyone can provide so much details and do research as some may have "less" clarity in the subject of the question. And now, I just need some support on why my questions were downvoted. So that it will definitely help me in the future. Can people who are downvoting at least specify the reason?

Comment: see also https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12919/36194

Comment: The canonical is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)* (cross site).

Comment: Nearly all of my downvotes on questions are because of (1) blatant homework and (2) if the question is so poorly worded that it is incomprehensible. Even then, it is mostly (1) for me.