# Why are there so many downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Is it because the quality of questions is low? Or is the Physics stackexchange a bit more hostile than other ones? Should the physics stackexchange community work harder on being more welcoming?

(also, meta-meta if this gets downvoted too)

Comment: Down voting here is different than down voting on the main site, by the way.

Comment: Do you have quantitative data to support your claim that in this community there are more downvotes than in the rest? Without actual numbers, this discussion is completely sterile.

Comment: I thought there was data about this on a meta question somewhere...I'll look for it.

Comment: [data on downvote #](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6762/121464)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We seem to be over-eager to downvote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6754/)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'm not sure hard numbers are that necessary on this account. The difference is immediate and obvious when using, say, the Mathematica or TeX sites.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I submit that both of the above have comparatively much less “homework”-type questions.  I also think that, because Mma and TeX are more specialized software, the typical contributor to those sites is different than the typical PSE contributor.

Comment: @Zero That may well be the case. (I tend to see the site cultures as so different that no single factor can be blamed, though.) But the point was simply that the differences exist, and that they're obvious enough that claiming their existence does not require detailed numerical evidence.