# Why are up voting and down voting thresholds different?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

To me down votes and up votes should be earned at the same time, but I want to know what the rationale behind them being different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered in the [privileges section of the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

> **The [up-vote](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top.** Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing. *(Emphasis mine)*

In addition to the thresholds being different, there's also a penalty of 1 rep for downvoting answers. The rationale for this is described in [this Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: I read them and it didn make sense to me

Comment: but thank you for explaining a bit more

Comment: also why are some people harsher than others when up/down vetoing

Comment: @Luna A lot of that is because people have different reasons for downvoting. For instance, I downvote almost all questions which I flag/VtC on the main site, so I have a large proportion of downvotes. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6754 expresses a lot of different opinions related to this subject, in the question, answers and (most importantly) comments.

Comment: ok that makes sense thank you explaining