# How can this answer have so many upvotes?

Tags: discussion

How can [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737563/why-high-frequency-has-high-energy/737570#737570) have so many upvotes? How is it even possible?

I implore you; go downvote this ridiculous answer. (And upvote correct answers!)

---

**Update:** The answer was deleted, thanks to Pat

Comment: I agree that this answer is bad, but each time I tried downvoting something, I got punished with a (admittedly very small, even symbolic) reputation penalty. Because of it, I tend to use the vote-to-close or vote-to-delete system rather than simple downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is -2 rep for downvoting an answer, whereas downvoting a question has no penalty. I think in this case it is worth it to take the small rep loss to downvote such a ridiculous answer. Also, the loss of rep goes away if the user deletes the answer, which I hope they will.

Comment: No, it is -1 for downvoting. -2 is for the *"receiver"* of the downvote.

Comment: Good to know. :)

Comment: Can anyone please explain why this answer is "ridiculous"? It looks perfectly fine to me, although I am probably missing something. I don't think we can discuss whether the answer should be removed/downvoted before actually establishing that it is, in fact, a bad/wrong answer...

Comment: Because it is applying incorrect classical reasoning to a purely quantum phenomenon. The answerer has confused *power* with *energy*!

Comment: For example, the photoelectric effect can not be explained in classical terms. Or do you disagree?

Comment: there is nothing "purely quantum mechanical" about EM waves having a frequency-dependent energy density. In classical electromagnetism, the energy of a wave is proportional to the frequency-squared. The answer is perfectly fine at explaining this: faster shaking equals more energy. Of course, the energy also depends on the amplitude, and bigger shaking also means more energy. But, amplitude being equal, it is indeed correct that, the faster you shake, the more energy the wave carries. OP never said anything about the photoelectric effect, and I am not sure how it is relevant here...

Comment: I agree with @AccidentalFourierTransform that this was a reasonably fine answer. Especially when you consider that a photon has to be a complete wavelength. The top criticism was that you could classically have it produce more photons at a lower frequency. That's not true since the frequency of one photon would have to correspond to the frequency of shaking. After all, classically, EM waves are propagations of changes in the EM field. The frequencies must match, so faster shaking makes higher energy photons. It's not a rigorous answer, but it's not terrible.

Comment: Well, I guess some of what you say is true, but it still seems to me a pretty poor answer that is confused and confusing.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on OPs question, OP stated: "Since all moving **particles** here would have the same speed..." To me this "particles" reads as "photons." Are you reading this as some other type of "particles" like 17th century "corpuscles of light" contemplated by Newton? To me, this reads as a question directed at photons and their energy as described in the relation: $E=hf$. I don't think other readings are as likely. But I have asked OP to clarify.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform From one point of view (classical), the answer is fine. From the other (quantum), people have reservations. I think the quantum view was not at all the intent of the OP, even though he did use the word "particle" which is strictly quantum mechanical. Perhaps all this can be solved by an edit to the original post, in line with what the OP was most likely thinking? This way, there can be no ambiguity and no need to downvote etc.

Comment: Anyways, here's what the OP said his question is about: "i [sic] am concerned about **photons** energy specifically in radio waves range of spectrum. But the information should be general and true for entire emr spectrum" (Emphasis added.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because our meta site is not for litigating the correctness of individual answers or soliciting up- or downvotes on individual posts. The way to express your opinion on the quality of a post is by voting on it and/or leaving a comment. Please refrain from directing attention towards individual posts in this manner in the future.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for acting on the (not so subtle) hint I dropped in my answer. With my answer being negatively received, I was starting to think this community had changed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This happens all the time with closed questions. Why is it legitimate to attract attentions to close votes received by a post on Meta, but not to other aspects of votes received by posts?

Comment: @Miyase This is the *wrong* behavior by the design of SE: Incorrect answers should be downvoted. Voting to close will *not* work on wrong answers, only on those which do not address the question, or have serious *non-scientific* reasons. (Whether this is good or not: Different story -- but this is how SE works.) -- I also find it rather disturbing that you rather save 1 reputation point (I mean -- what does it buy you?) instead of working towards improving the quality of the content of the site through upvoting good and also downvoting bad content.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch "Why was this question closed?"/"I think this question should be reopened because <argument>" are essentially discussions about site policy since we *do* have policy that governs which questions should be closed/not closed. We do emphatically *not* have *debatable policies* that dictate how you should use your up- and down-votes - just the general SE rules about targeted voting/sockpuppetry, upvote stuff you find useful, downvote stuff you don't etc.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I see your point. Yet, there have been discussions about voting behavior here on Meta, e.g. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6754/we-seem-to-be-over-eager-to-downvote/, and they have not been closed. Should they? (In fact, some like the linked one led to good discussions and answers.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I see a stark difference between between a discussion of voting behavior in general and a post that is essentially just "go downvote this answer" + insulting the answer as "ridiculous". Aside from the unnecessary hostility, there isn't even any argument here for *why* the post should be downvoted, so there is nothing to discuss. There probably is a version of this question that is suitable for meta; the current one is not it.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree that it's somewhat irrational, but I certainly could understand your post without the insulting undertones in words like "disturbing". In a nutshell, I contribute my free time to help the site with answers and reviews. Downvoting is a perfectly fine tool, but on this site it comes with a strange drawback. It's not about measurable consequences, it's about the feeling of being punished while I'm volunteering to help. I'll keep helping if I can, but not with this tool.

Comment: @Miyase My apologies if the "disturbing" came across as insulting. Maybe "puzzling" would have been more accurate. But I *do* find it puzzling that you see a bad answer (which might even have upvotes) and you don't feel like this should be made clear that it is bad, before people read this and think that this is the right answer (like, indeed, the one this is all about) ... But then again, I am rather high up in downvotes (not as much as ACuriousMind, but not too far), so maybe it's rather me who is behaving in a non-standard way ...

Comment: @ACuriousMind *"There probably is a version of this question that is suitable for meta; the current one is not it. "* -- I can subscribe to that. So really more "low quality" than "off topic".

Answer (score 2):

An answer can have a large number of upvotes any time there are enough users that find it helpful and accurate. I believe that addresses all of the questions in this post, however I will continue addressing the spirit of your post.

If you disagree with its accuracy, you should downvote it and leave a comment for the author with suggested corrections, or post a correct answer yourself. However, the author is still free to post the answer at the risk of downvotes and/or votes to delete. If other users disagree with your appraisal, they might still continue to upvote the answer.

If you feel it has been upvoted far more than it should and deserves some focus from users on that front, then a proper strategy might be to point this out on the hbar. This keeps our Meta site clean and free from examples of us mass shaming specific answers that we do or do not agree with.